# What is the proof for boundedness of the following LP problem?

Tags: linear-programming

\begin{array}{ll}
\text{maximize}  & Ax + By \\
\text{subject to}& Cz + Dw = 1 \\
& A’x + B’y \le C’z + D’w  \\
&x, y, z, w \ge 0.
\end{array}

where A, B, C, D, A’, B’, C’, D’ are constant positive 1×n matrix 
and x, y, z, w are n×1 matrix.

What is the proof for boundedness of the above LP model?
Is it bounded or not? If not, with what conditions the model is bounded?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried so far? What does it mean if a LP is bounded? Please show your attempt and specify your question.

Comment: In maximization problem, it means having an upper bound for the objective function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dual is:
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{minimize}  & \theta \\
\text{subject to}& \lambda A' \ge A \\
& \lambda B' \ge B  \\
& -\lambda C' + \theta C \ge 0  \\
& -\lambda D' + \theta D \ge 0  \\
&\lambda \ge 0, \theta free.
\end{array}